# Stream Audio from Ubuntu Desktop to Android Mobile via bluetooth

Tags: 16.04, bluetooth, android

Is there any way to play music on your PC and stream it to your android phone via bluetooth, e.g I want to play a youtube video on computer and listen that audio via my phone.

Comment: This is really a question about Android. Theoretically this is possible, but you need an app on the Android device itself, which exposes the device as a bluetooth speaker with A2DP profile, so audio can be streamed to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah!
I explain the way I used (which worked) but I don't know if it's the only method one... You need to use **bluetooth** and **pulseaudio**:

- pair PC and phone
- set the phone as *external speaker* via `pavucontrol` application on the PC

Comment: Could you please elaborate on _how_ did you set the phone as external speaker via pavucontrol?

Comment: After you paired the two devices, the *phone* appears in the *device* tab but this is not important... you need to go in the *playback* tab and choose your phone from the drop-down menu of the (currently playing media) application you want the sound to re-direct to. PS: I don't have it at the moment on my hand so I can't be precise nor sure about steps